# Why is the system stopping me from answering?

Tags: bug, reputation

My reputation is 109 (at the time of asking this question). I was trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po). But it says my that:

> **Highly active question**. Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

I have enough reputation, so why am I seeing this message?

Comment: They must have changed the protected question message a while back, it *used* to make it clear that the association bonus doesn't count but now it doesn't say that for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm afraid you don't have enough reputation earned directly on this site. 100 of your reputation comes from the association bonus and that [doesn't count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-the-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question) to answer protected questions.